# Automapper Compile Mappings asp.net core

Tags: automapper

I'm using the following syntax in my asp.net core startup class to configure automapper:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(c => c.AllowNullCollections = true, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I'd like to be able to compile the mappings at startup.

According to the Automapper docs, I should be able to do so via:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
configuration.CompileMappings();
```

How do I get access to the mapping configuration using AddServices syntax?

Comment: You need to inject `IConfigurationProvider` somewhere in the start-up code.

Comment: so I can get access to the configuration provider by injecting it (it appears to be a singleton), and I can call CompileMappings(), but that doesn't seem to be compiling the instance used by the singleton Mapper instance. Calling Mapper.Map<DestType>(SrcInstance) t he first time can take up to 8 seconds.  The 2nd time, its very fast.  When I inject the ConfigurationProvider and call compile it takes several seconds to compile, but then my first call to Mapper.Map still takes 8 seconds.

Comment: All this sounds very wrong :) Upgrade the DI package and remove all usage of the static mapper.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of automapper, and have NO static instances of mapper in my codebase. Everything is injected via the .net core DI system

Comment: Then I don't know what singleton mapper instance you're talking about. There is no such thing. Anyway, you can easily remove the DI stuff and make a simple test without it.

Comment: I guess 8 seconds is a very long time. If you can make a repro, I'll look into it.

Comment: The singleton I'm referring to is the registration of the IConfigurationProvider into the service collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject an instance of `IConfigurationProvider` from the AutoMapper assembly and configure AutoMapper this way. For example, you could use the `Configure()` Startup Method like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IConfigurationProvider mapperConfiguration)
{
    mapperConfiguration.CompileMappings();
}
```

Or do it programmatically:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var mapperConfiguration = app.ApplicationServices
                                 .GetRequiredService<IConfigurationProvider>();
    mapperConfiguration.CompileMappings();
}
```